# When Initializing object, instance variable not initialized always?

Tags: java, initialization, instance-variables

The following code produces NullPointerException -

```
public class MyClass {

    static MyClass instance= new MyClass(); // line 3
    static Boolean have_Instance = true;
    Boolean inst_Avail=have_Instance; // line 5

    Boolean isInstAvail(){
        return inst_Avail;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(instance.isInstAvail() ? "Instance is there.":""); // gives java.lang.NullPointerException
    }

}
```

If I move `line 3` to after `line 5`, it runs fine. How does the order matter here? Shouldn't instantiation of a class set iVar values everytime?

Comment: Uuuh... What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 3):

When an object is created on line 3 the class has not finished initializing yet, and the `have_instance` variable has its default value, `null`. This value is assigned to the `inst_Avail` member variable of the object, so the value returned by `instance.isInstAvail()` in the `main` method will be `null`.

An easy way to fix this is swapping lines 3 and 4, so `have_instance` already has a value when the object is created. Or you could declare `have_instance` as `boolean` instead of `Boolean`, so it will have the value `false` and not `null`. This would make the program print nothing though.

Or maybe you could rethink what you're trying to do. It's rarely a good idea to create instances of a class before the class has finished initializing, especially if the class is not "final" (i.e. may have subclasses).

Comment: When you swap lines 3 and 4 the `have_instance` variable will be set before the instance is created, so yes, doing that makes the program print `Instance is there.` Why would there be an endless loop of new instances?

Answer (score 2):

The order of fields matter if you initialize these fields either directly by setting their values or using a static initializer block. They are executed in order. So you couldn't do a forward reference:

```
private int someInt = 10 + otherInt;
private int otherInt = 22;
```

This won't work, because the fields are initialized in order of their textual declaration. If you have two static initializers, they will be executed in order as well:

```
static { System.out.println("first"); }
static { System.out.println("second"); }
```

So in your case, you initialize `instance` before `have_instance`, so the latter is still `null` (default value for non-primitives). The JVM will create a `MyClass` object to be assigned to `instance` and initialize its fields, i.e. assign the value of `have_instance` to `inst_Avail` which will be set to `null` as well.

**Some readings:**

- [Object initialization in Java](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html)

Answer (score 1):

This code is really weird and I dont see use-cases for this, but this would do the fix:

```
public class MyClass {

    static MyClass instance; // line 3
    static Boolean have_Instance = true;
    Boolean inst_Avail=have_Instance; // line 5

    Boolean isInstAvail(){
        return inst_Avail;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        instance = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(instance.isInstAvail() ? "Instance is there.":""); // gives     java.lang.NullPointerException
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this could be to make inst_Avail as static, so that at the time of loading the class, this variable is instantiated:

```
 private static  Boolean inst_Avail=have_Instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning `static` variable value to `non-static` variable

i.e.

```
Boolean inst_Avail=have_Instance;
```

either make it `static` or

assign `inst_Avail = true` in the `constructor`